# Round to 2 numbers after the Point

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is an example of what my column has into:

```
-5,17363929475323E-14
1,4210854715202E-14
1,3855583347322E-13
-2,8421709430404E-14
-1,4210854715202E-14
3,5527136788005E-15
3,5527136788005E-15
1,24344978758018E-14
-5,6843418860808E-14
```

and I want to round them only for 2 digits after the colon

so the it will be :

```
-5,17
1,42
1,39
....
```

I tried

```
CAST (-1,4210854715202E-14 AS decimal (19,2)),
ROUND (-1,4210854715202E-14,2)
convert(decimal(38,2), -1,4210854715202E-14)
```

Non of them worked....

Comment: The number `-1.4210854715202E-14` is *nowhere near* `1.42`, not by a very long shot.

Comment: Make sure you get the commas and points correctly, try changing this -1,4210854715202E-14 to -1.4210854715202E-14

Answer (score 5):

Mathematically the number `-1,4210854715202E-14` means `-0,000000000000014210854715202`. So, obviously this will gives you `0,00` when you cast or round it to 2 decimals, the actual value is far smaller than Zero.

Answer (score 1):

This this the shortest mantissa you can have for float data type

```
select cast (-1.4210854715202E-14 as float (1))
-1,421085E-14
```

Mind decimal point character '.'

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, if you want the first three significant decimal places, here is one method:

```
select ((case when val < 0 then '-' else '' end) +
        left(convert(varchar(32), abs(val), 1), 4)
       )
```

How does this work?  The format "1", for a number, always uses scientific notation for the conversion.  You want the first four digits (two after the decimal place, the decimal place, and the first one).  There could be a negative sign, so this is added afterwards.